# Minimum secure message size over SSL

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, cryptography

What is the minimum size a message should be in order to remain secure when sent over SSL/HTTPS? My understanding is that having a very small message can make cracking it easier because there are fewer possible values the initial payload could have, making it possible to just brute force encrypt them all and check the result of each.

My guess is it would be about the size of the key used to encrypt it, so if my site is protected with 256-bit SSL, what is the minimum size of payload I should send, even if I just fill it with random data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL messages get filled with random data anyway in most if not all cipher suites anyway. If you send one byte over SSL it becomes about 43 bytes on the wire due to padding, MACs, headers, and whatever else, depending again on the cipher suite.